# How to use apache to reach pen drives

Tags: raspbian, web-server, apache-httpd

I want to use apache to host the files of my two pen drives but also from a folder inside /home/pi. I can set the root directory of apache to /home/pi but what about the pen drives? Don't wanna set the directory to / because I only want to make /media and /home/pi/downloads accesible through apache.

Answer (score 3):

You can create symlinks in this directory and add this option to you site config:

```
 <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
 </Directory>
```

Comment: If you don't know what a symlink is, [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link).  An example of creating a symlink on linux would be `ln -s /mnt/usb/foo /var/httpd/bar`.  This links the latter to the former.  The `-s` important, see `man ln`.